# GetFeature throws IndexOutOfBounds exception

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I can run a query like this using WFS 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 (the response is slightly different). But, why do I get IndexOutOfBounds exception when I try with WFS 2.0.0?

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=tiger:poi&maxFeatures=2&filter=<PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>NAME</PropertyName><Literal>lox</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo>
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the filter syntax may have changed between WFS versions.  Do you get the same error if you wrap your filter value with some filter elements?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the section B.8 KVP Examples in the WFS 2.0 standard your request is mostly correct. According to the example everything should be enclosed inside "Filter" but Geoserver does accept the filter even without it.

```
FILTER=<Filter><Within><PropertyName>InWaterA_1M/wkbGeom<PropertyName> <gml:Envelope><gml:lowerCorner>10 10</gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>20 20</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope></Within></Filter>
```

The reason for the issue is that GeoServer wants to qualify that "Filter" actually means "fes:Filter as written in the WFS 2.0 standard:

> XML-encoded predicate expressions shall be encoded using the
>   fes:Filter element as described in ISO 19143:2010, sub clause 7.2.

You can make the filter to work by defining the namespace of Filter in the request:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=tiger:poi&Count=2&FILTER=%3CFilter%20xmlns=%22http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0%22%3E%3CPropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3CPropertyName%3ENAME%3C/PropertyName%3E%3CLiteral%3Elox%3C/Literal%3E%3C/PropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3C/Filter%3E
```

I can't say if GeoServer is right or wrong. The standard says

> To be rigorously correct, these examples should include namespace and
>   schema location information in the root element, fes:Filter

Thus, GeoServer is here "rigorously correct" but on the other hand, perhaps the current behavior can be considered to be a bug.